# How RAM does Ubuntu accept in 32 and 64 bit?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, ram, 32-bit

I would like to make a question. I will install Ubuntu OS along my Windows Enterprise 10 x64 bit. When I go to ubuntu.com to download the operating system I see like alternative options 2 version : 32 & 64 bit.

My computer is Fujitsu Siemens with the details shows in photo below. I like to know if the 32-bit version know 5 GB of RAM ?

[image]

Comment: If you have a 32-bit system then go for the 32-bit option, if you have a 64-bit system then go for the 64-bit option, it's simple.

Comment: Go for 64 bit, which will have multiarch support (means you can install both 64bit and 32bit packages). On a 32bit system, you can not install 64bit software. It will also use your CPU more efficiently, although RAM usage might be minimally higher with 64bit. This should not be a problem as you have more than 4GB RAM though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 32-bit version can *theoretically* use up to 64GB of RAM thanks to PAE, see this question: [It is secure to upgrade the RAM of a 32-bit Server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/830759/518562)

**But**. Why in the world would you *want* the 32-bit version? 64-bit is better in so many ways. You have an x64 compatible CPU and 5GB of RAM, so get the 64-bit version! :)

Comment: Thanks . I have downloaded and installed the 64 version of uBuntu . Is working fine, as I am new here that why I decided to ask about. Thank you again ;)